# Sorting doesn't work with templated class

Tags: c++, templates, overloading, operator-keyword

I have an insertion sort function

```
   void insertionSort(ArrayList<int> myData)
    {

      for (int i = 1; i < myData.getSize(); i++) {

      int index = myData[i];
      int j = i;

      while (j > 0 && myData[j-1] > index) {
         myData.swap(j - 1, j);
         j--;
        }
       myData[j] = index;

      }

    }
```

which uses this swap function

```
   template<class TYPE>
   void ArrayList<TYPE>::swap(int from, int to) throw(std::out_of_range)
  {
     int temp = 0;
     temp = this->items[from];
     this->items[from] = this->items[to];
     this->items[to] = temp;

     swapNum++;
   }
```

This is how my private methods look like

```
TYPE * items;
int currentLength;
static int swapNum;
```

I have an overloaded [] operator and a getSize() function that I think I wrote well and not contributing to my problem. Now if I do this in my main.cpp

```
     ArrayList<int>m_Data(1);
```

and append say 4,2,9,1 on the m_Data and call

```
     insertionSort(m_Data);
```

I get two errors

```
    1. Error    C2440   '=': cannot convert from 'std::string' to 'int'
```

on the swap function and

```
    2. The insertion sort doesn't work
```

Comment: /OT: Don't use the obsolete `throw` specifiers, they don't do anything else and aren't enforced, so there is little to no point in using them.

Comment: 1. is most likely from `int temp = this->items[from];` 2. would be a strange error message from a compiler.

Comment: Shouldn't `temp` be declared as `TYPE`, not hard-coded as `int`? And there's no need to initialize it, since it's assigned on the next line.

Comment: Your `insertionSort` function works on copy of `ArrayList` object, so you sort local object, after calling this function passed object was not changed.

Comment: @Rakete1111 I have a test function that catches the throw

Comment: @rafix07 The `ArrayList` class has an `items` pointer. If the copy has the same pointer, it will update the original.

Comment: @OlafDietsche Yes that's the exact line I get the error from

Comment: @Mykel You misunderstood his comment. He wasn't saying "don't use try-catch". He was saying the throw list after the decl but before the body of the function is pointless. The `throw(std::out_of_range)` specifically was what he was talking about. It's pointless; get rid of it.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks the first error went away after I changed temp to TYPE. But, the sorting still doesn't work

Comment: @WhozCraig Sure. Thanks. I have

Comment: @rafix07 Come again? I didn't get that

Comment: @Mykel It was my mistake, i was wrong, Barmar's comment is right.

Comment: Although a copy constructor that copies the pointer is usually poor design, unless you're using smart pointers. Otherwise the destructor can't know whether to free the array.

Comment: @Mykel Have you defined copy constructor and destructor of `ArrayList`? Put more code. Try to use `void insertionSort(ArrayList<int>& myData)` and check result of sorting.

Comment: @Barmar I think my destructor is poorly implemented too and can't properly free the array. But does that affect the insertion sort?

Comment: @Mykel If it frees the array, then you'll try to access invalid memory after the `insertionSort()` function returns.

Comment: Thanks it worked! @rafix07 Why that tho? Why the address of myData?

Comment: @Barmar Thanks I understand. I have implemented my destructor as delete [] items . Is that right? basically delete items after it's done

Comment: @Mykel Without `&` your `myData` object was passed by value, so copy of this object was made, if you implemented correctly copy constructor, new array was created - `items` and all changes were made on this array, after calling `insertionSort` local `myData` is deleted and you cannot see correct result. When you operate on original object (it is passed by reference `&`) you see original changed object.

Comment: @Mykel We need to see more of the class implementation. If the constructor uses `new` then it's correct to use `delete` in the destructor, but then the changes you make to the copy won't affect the original. If the constructor doesn't use `new` then you shouldn't `delete` in the destructor.

Comment: @Barmar **template<class TYPE>
ArrayList<TYPE>::ArrayList(int initialSize)
{
 maxLength = initialSize;
 currentLength = 0;
 items = new TYPE[initialSize];
 originalLength = initialSize;
}**                                                                 That's how I implemented my constructor and it utilizes new. But it seems my destructor throws an error

Comment: That's not the copy constructor. Did you follow the [rule of 3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming))?

Comment: Put your code in the question, not comments. And in comments, use backticks to mark code, not bold.

Comment: @Barmar Sorry, I misunderstood, I don't have a copy constructor

Comment: Then you're not following the rule, which is a serious problem with your code.

Comment: @Barmar what my code is doing doesn't require it. Should I still implement it?

Comment: It definitely does need it. You don't make a new array in the copy constructor, so when that object is destructed it will delete the array. That invalidates the `items` pointer in the original object that was copied.

Comment: That's the whole reason for the Rule of Three.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First problem: it should be something like `TYPE temp = this->items[from]`. After repairing it (I used STL swap) function works. Well, it works on STL vector and swap. If you still do have problem, then your array structure is probably invalid.

EDIT: In function 'insertionSort' shouldn't you have template (as in swap function)?

Comment: Thanks a lot. That error went away. I am still struggling on the insertion sort

Comment: After changing ArrayList to vector<int>, it works (I tested on my PC), so both insertion sort and swap function aren't corrupted.

Comment: So that means it has something to do with how I implemented my ArrayList class? or my constructor